# WF Designer Extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am trying to write an extension for the WF Designer in Visual Studio which should listen to click/double click events on Activities.

The problem is that I can't find any good documents that describe how to extend the Visual Studio worklow designer.

So what I am looking for is a way to access the WorkflowDesigner object which is hosted in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Some Google Research lead me to the following pages:

[msdn.microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680901.aspx)

Which suggests you to:

1. Add a reference from the host project to the activity library project containing the custom activity.
2. Build the solution.
3. To use the custom activity in the designer, locate the custom activity in the toolbox, and drag the activity onto the designer surface.
4. To use the custom activity in code, add a Using statement that refers to the custom activity project, and pass a new instance of the activity to Invoke.

---

[blog.msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2012/10/04/wf4-vs-workflowdesigner-extensions-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Which gives you an tip where to place workflow designer extension DLLs so that VS will find them

---

EDIT: I have never written an extension for the WF Designer, but i will try it out as well now, since there are a few things that i want to improve.

Comment: I already know this blog entry. The problem is that I would like to extend the Designer so that I can listen to double click events on activities and react to them. This works perfectly when I rehost the designer - but I can't find a way to access the internal Visual Studio WorkflowDesigner-object

Comment: this should not be possible,(my thought so far was that it is boxed?)  but let me do some researches

Comment: That is also my impression - seems to be hidden inside a MAF-Addin and I can't find a way to get access to the designer object (tried to somehow get access by using reflection). Would be nice to somehow get access to "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.Addin. WorkflowDesignerAddIn" - which is hosting the designer object.

Comment: @eggi i think i have found something, take a look at this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd695719.aspx

Comment: Seems not very helpful for me. I need a way to globally subscribe to the double click event of the workflow designer. I need this because I would like to build a VS plugin which should be able to navigate to the code of activities from the designer (like Resharper does for code files).

Comment: I think you need listen to click/double click events on activities first,  and you could consider use the method mentioned above.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454690/in-workflow-need-to-listen-for-multiple-events